# How could I create a hyperlink that extracts the Account Name from a People/Groups Display Field?

Tags: user-profile-property, display-form

I have a DVWP with some data any a People/Groups field. Adjacent to each People/Groups field, I would like to include a "View Information" link that sends the current user to [site]/Pages/information.aspx?Name={Account Name} where {Account Name} is the account name of the listed person (typically domain\whatever).

I am finding this to be rather challenging since I can expose Account Name of "current user" through jQuery but can't find a way to expose it for just an item in a DispForm.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you are after by using the [ddwrt:UserLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143%28v=office.11%29.aspx) function.

```
<xsl:variable name="UserFieldLogin">
   <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup(string(@UserField) ,'Login')" />
</xsl:variable>

<a href="[site]/Pages/information.aspx?Name={$UserFieldLogin}"> 
<xsl:value-of select="@UserField"/></a>
```

Comment: That looks perfect on paper - and many searches, but I cannot make it work. I keep getting the same escaped user data in there (replacing specifics with elipses): "http...information.aspx?Name=<nobr><span><A HREF=".../_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=...">...,...</A><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/><a href='javascript:' onclick='IMNImageOnClick();return false;' class='ms-imnlink'><img name='imnmark' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='sip:...' id='imn_...,type=sip'/></a></span></nobr>